# How many access points do I need?

Tags: wifi

My company has 6 floors and each floor is roughly around 5000 sq ft. I was wondering to cover the whole building with wireless connections. 
So how many access point do I need to setup to cover the whole building ? 
How many switches and what kind of hardware, software, and transmission media do I need ? 
And what kind of other IT infrustrure do I might need for its network?

Thanks

Comment: How much is your budget?

Comment: budget is no matter, I just want something that fast, secure and hassle free

Comment: Is this just for Internet access? Or is there local file sharing and the like required too? Do you have an estimate for the total number of connected devices? Also, do you have an estimate for the total bandwidth. (Is the whole network to share a DSL connection? Or are we trying to do wireless video to dozens of projectors? Big difference.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, It's suppose to use only for file sharing, there is no internet access. There are 400 people working and each one has one PC and 100 shared printers. With visitors from outside we have approximately 1000 users almost everyday. There is no wireless video sharing. The CCTV and video sharing is from different company who has their own infrastructure settled in first floor.

Comment: @SoheilBm: Definitely hire a consultant then.

Comment: 100 printers??!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most wireless AP providers won't support more than 50 clients per AP.  That's 50 devices, not 50 users.

Each user has on average 2.5 devices.  A laptop, a smartphone (and a tablet).

Quick and dirty estimate says that you'll need 20 access points.  You'll need a site survey to figure out how the signal will *actually* cover.

You'll also need some [pretty hardcore switching](http://tomoconnor.eu/blogish/answered-network-design/#.UK9n7uOTs-0).

You'll similarly need some kind of wireless LAN controller to  handle the authentication and BYOD (Bring Your Own Device) requirements (if you're doing BYOD).  I wouldn't even consider managing a network of this size and scale without a WLAN controller.

The most expensive things are going to be the network infrastructure, and the consultant's time to set it all up.

Comment: +1, I was thinking 4 APs per floor, controller(s)... Using Refurb gear it'd still be at dead minimum around $7000 USD for the hardware. Add installation. Then configuration and either support or training... Definitely pricey enough that he'll want a consultant who will get it right.

Answer (score 1):

What are your walls and floor made of? What are the dimensions of the floors? How many users will be accessing it? How good are the antennas on their devices? How much bandwidth do they require? How much bandwidth will they use?

It's not possible to provide an answer to your question, even if you supplied a LOT more information.

However you might want to start by getting a single access point and example mobile device and surveying your building to get an estimate of how many access points you might need.

Comment: Almost over 1000 people is going to access it. The walls are made of paper and are so light. I still not sure what Access point should I use to cover more? What do you recommend ?

Comment: Is that 1000 people in total, or 1000 people on each floor?

Comment: 'My Company has 6 floors'...'the walls are made of paper'. I recommend a crash helmet. And that you carry out a site survey using a single AP / mobile device.

Comment: I meant the wall that separate the rooms @symcbean

Comment: 1000 people in total